# Ruby: access to attr_accessor's method from internal method

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I have a code:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :somevar

  def a
    somevar = 'something'
    puts @somevar
  end

  def b
    send :somevar=, 'something'
    puts @somevar
  end

end

A.new.a #=> nil
A.new.b #=> 'something'
```

Why is there a difference? Why can't I just assign an instance variable through a writer? But why local variable has been created instead of method (setter) has been called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`attr_accessor :somevar` references the **instance** variable `@somevar`. Instance variables must be preceded by the `@` sign.  All other variables like 'somevar' without an `@` sign in a method are just local variables to that method or scope, not instance variables for the object.

Thus, changing the first line in method "a" to

```
@somevar = 'something'
```

will result in the answer you expect.

Related note: you don't have to declare instance variables in Ruby, you just create them with `@somevar` type notation.  The `attr_accessor` method creates setters and getters for that instance variable.

Methods in Ruby are attached to objects, so in order for class A to invoke its own somevar setter method, you would need to write `self.somevar = 'something'`, otherwise the Ruby parser thinks you are just creating a local variable.

This could be confusing because you could invoke method `a` from `b`, by just doing:

```
def b
  send :somevar=,'something'
  puts @somevar
  a  # would invoke its own method 'a'
end
```

But the setter method `somevar=` is ambiguous with creating a local variable with the same notation:

```
somevar='something'  # Ruby assumes you want to create a local variable
```

So to call the somevar setter method you need to explicitly say that you are calling the method on self with:

```
self.somevar = 'something'
```

When you called `send :somevar=,'something'` you were invoking the somevar instance method also.

Comment: But why local variable has been created instead of method (setter) has been called?

Comment: Methods in Ruby are attached to objects, so in order class A to invoke its own somevar setter method, you would need to write `self.somevar = 'something'`, otherwise the Ruby parser thinks you are just creating a local variable.  I updated my answer above to explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It's because method a is creating a local variable called somevar. It's just one of Ruby's little quirks. You can get around this by doing `self.somevar = 'something'` or `@somevar = 'something'`.

Comment: But why? Method with the same name exits but local variable has created?

Comment: It's probably for safety reasons. If you didn't realize you had a setter method called `somevar` and started using it thinking you were setting a local variable, it would be overwriting this value without you knowing it.